# Coding challenge I couldn't figure out

Tags: javascript

I recently came across something I thought would be rather easy to complete. The situation was this:

Fix the code so that all statements pass.

```
    function myFunction(s) {
        var c = s[0];
        // if the user enters an uppercase letter, return uppercase
        if(c === c.toUpperCase()) {
            return "uppercase";
        // if the user enters a lowercase letter, return lowercase
        } else if(c === c.toLowerCase()) {
            return "lowercase"; 
        // if the user enters a number, return digit
        } else if(!isNan(c)) {
            return "digit";
        } else {
            return "other";
        }
    }
```

I could get the first two to work perfectly fine by entering c === toUpperCase and toLowerCase methods. However when I entered a number into myFunction(1), it would always return a typeError.

I could not figure out why. I made the assumption that I possibly don't understand why we are reassigning s to s[0].

Can anyone explain to me what I would need to do to get all return values correctly?

Comment: Could you show us the actual code you came up with. It's probably going to be better for you to learn why it didn't work rather than just be given an answer.

Comment: Also take a look at `typeof`, as far as checking if something is an actual number type

Comment: Did you pass a number or a string to your function, i.e. was it `myFunction(1)` or `myFunction('1')`? If the value has been entered by a user it's likely to be a string value rather than numeric!

Comment: @Taplar, Edited

Comment: Ok, so think about what you got so far.  If you pass in a true number as the variable, array access `[0]` doesn't make sense, and both two upper and lower don't make sense.  Those are string methods.  So #1) confirm that the question wants you to pass in a true number and not a number as a string, and if so #2) consider how the logic needs to address that.  Given that the question explicitly points out the places you "need to fix", I would assume they expect you to pass in only strings.

Comment: @Taplar, I don't really understand why they're saying 'var c = s[0]'. I think if I understand that I could figure out why this returns a typeError. I thought maybe I could use parseInt(c) but that doesn't work either. I mean, wouldn't s[0] be returning an array of index 0?

Comment: Given `s` is a *string*, `s[0]` extracts the first character from that string (still a string with length 1). Hence the variable name `c`, I suppose. In case of empty strings, `c` is `undefined`, so maybe that case needs to be handled. Also: there's no builtin `isNan`, only `isNaN`, but makes no sense with strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are accessing the first character of the input, so making an assumption that you are passing a string

You can try something like this:

```
function myFunction(s) {
        var c = s[0];
        // if the user enters an uppercase letter, return uppercase
        if( c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') {
            return "uppercase";
        // if the user enters a lowercase letter, return lowercase
        } else if(c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') {
            return "lowercase"; 
        // if the user enters a number, return digit
        } else if(!isNaN(c)) {
            return "digit";
        } else {
            return "other";
        }
    }
```

Sample Test:

```
myFunction("78")
"digit"

myFunction("%")
"other"

myFunction("S")
"uppercase"

myFunction("d")
"lowercase"
```

Comment: Do you have to just assume that the users input is always a string? Or is that just by default?

Comment: @NickWilson - I am considering input as string because in the code, its trying to access the first index of the input, which will be udefined in case you pass an integer. i.e if s = 5 then s[0] will be undefined. And when you try to check if it's a number or not by adding condition !isNaN(undefined) will give false and your default condition will be executed.

Comment: I think I get it. By my original methods, if I entered 1, it is still considered a string value. So I have to compare aA - zZ. Let's just say I probably didn't get that job. lol